# Relative units CSS clip-path?

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I'm trying to define a `clip-path` do a given element.
On Chrome there aren't problems (thanks polygon!), but on Firefox I can't find a way to obtain the same result using the `url` alternative.

This clip-path will just cut the entire element on Firefox, and I can't find a way to make it work the proper way.
As you can see, it should use relative values.

**css**:

```
.element {
  clip-path: url(../jobs-shape.svg#path);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 15%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

**svg**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="path">
      <polygon points="0 0, 1 0.15, 1 1, 0 1" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Ah! Nevermind, found the solution.

I have to use `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0 0, 1 0.15, 1 1, 0 1" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```